# Quiero ejecutar un codigo del libro PYTHON A FONDO DE OSCAR RAMIREZ (Marcombo) y me se un TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' or' Puede que math?

Tags: python, visual-studio, archivo, math, python-import

https://stackoverflow.com
[Texto](https://stackoverflow.com)
[Texto](https://stackoverflow.com)
[image: Imagen de VS-Code]

[image: El error en ejecucion]

[image: Ejemplo img.1][image: otra del ejemplo que la el libro]

import math

def hola_mundo() :
print('Hola Mundo')

def calcular_raiz_cuadrada(num) :
return math.sqrt(num)

def funcion_principal(longitud) :
hola_mundo()
print[(x * 2 for x in range(longitud))]
while True:
num = float(input('Introduzaca un numero: '))
res = calcular_raiz_cuadrada(num)
print(f'La raiz cuadrada de {num} es {res}')

if **name** == '**main**' :
funcion_principal(10)

#Consola
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Como estás poniendo corchetes al lado del print, Python cree que intentas acceder a uno de sus items (como si fuera una lista o diccionario). La solución es poner parentesis alrededor de los corchetes. Si lo copiaste tal cual vino del libro, es posible que use Python 2, donde print NO era una función, si no una declaración.

Comment: Muchas grancias Sr. Dante, problema solucionado con su respuesta. Agradecido!!

Comment: De nada Federico!